# UITableView not rendering all sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView in it. I have 3 sections for the UITableView, like this.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}
```

and my cells set up like this...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier        = @"ContactInfoCellIdentifier";

    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
        {

            ...

            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {

            ...    
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {

            ...

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

but for some reason case 2, section 3 never gets called. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: What do you return for `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: it returns the count from an array, or 1 if the array is empty, so there should always be at least 1 row for each section

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the UITableViewCell like this `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"YourIdentifier"];`